# Plot logistic regression using parameters in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a logistic regression directly from the parameter estimates using ggplot2, but not quite sure how to do it.

For example, if I had 1500 draws of alpha and beta parameter estimates, I could plot each of the lines thus:

```
alpha_post = rnorm(n=1500,mean=1.1,sd = .15)
beta_post = rnorm(n=1500,mean=1.8,sd = .19)
X_lim = seq(from = -3,to = 2,by=.01)


for (i in 1:length(alpha_post)){
  print(i)
  y = exp(alpha_post[i] + beta_post[i]*X_lim)/(1+ exp(alpha_post[i] + beta_post[i]*X_lim) )

  if (i==1){plot(X_lim,y,type="l")}
  else {lines(X_lim,y,add=T)}
}
```

How would I do this in ggplot2? I know how to use geom_smooth(), but this is a little different.

Comment: can you add definition to `X_lim`? I get `Error in X_lim : object 'X_lim' not found`

Comment: I just did. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in ggplot, you want to make a data.frame with all data that needs to be plotted:

```
d <- data.frame(
  alpha_post = alpha_post, 
  beta_post = beta_post,
  X_lim = rep(seq(from = -3,to = 2,by=.01), each = length(alpha_post))
)
d$y <- with(d, exp(alpha_post + beta_post * X_lim) / (1 + exp(alpha_post + beta_post * X_lim)))
```

Then the plotting itself becomes quite easy:

```
ggplot(d, aes(X_lim, y, group = alpha_post)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

If you want to be more fancy, add a summary line with e.g. the mean:

```
ggplot(d, aes(X_lim, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = alpha_post), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = 'firebrick', stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So how would I plot the mean line after changing the color of the other lines?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. Maybe better to just add it to your answer. Here is what  I came up with. First, get median to new data.frame d.med = data.frame(
  alpha_post = median(d$alpha_post),
  beta_post = median(d$beta_post),
  X_lim = seq(from=-4,to=2,by=.01)
). Then, calculate predicted y as before. Finally, just add a new geom_line() with a different color.

Comment: @user44796 - you could compute the average for each value of `X_lim` and then plot that...here's a solution using data.table: `library(data.table); setDT(d); d_avg <- d[, mean(y), by = X_lim]; ggplot(d, aes(X_lim, y, group = alpha_post)) + geom_line() + geom_line(data = d_avg, mapping = aes(X_lim, V1, group = 1), colour = "red")`

Comment: @user44796, I've edited the answer. In the future, please ask your full question at the start.

Comment: @Axeman, I agree. I should have included in my initial question, but I wasn't thinking about it. I debated whether to ask a new question, but I thought it belonged here. Thanks again.